# Linker error - (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: c, xcode, compiler-errors, linker-errors, invocation

Often times upon compiling my 'c code' with Xcode, I get a "linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)" error.

I am interested in the "use -v to see invocation" statement. Where in Xcode can I "use -v" to see the invocation? Furthermore, is it useful in tracking down the error?

Regards,
Darrell

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use -v to see invocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247294/use-v-to-see-invocation)

Comment: This question as an answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48247294/use-v-to-see-invocation