# use -v to see invocation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker

I am having a serious linker problem on one of my iOS apps ([See previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48246467/build-failing-parse-server-pod-bolts) for details)

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

A basic question is: *How can I use -v to see the invocation?*

Is that an option that I can set somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click your project in the Project Navigator. Click the Build Settings tab. Find the Linking section. Under that, add `-v` to “Other Linker Flags”.

[image: other linker flags build setting]

You may need to clean your project or the build folder and rebuild to see the result in the build log.